# SimpleDateFormat shows time in 24-hours even after using "hh" for hour

Tags: java

Accoridng to `SimpleDateFormat`,

if i will use `hh` for hour, then i will get time in AM/PM, so I am trying this,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss Z");
System.out.println(sdf.parse("Jan 30 2014 09:07:32 GMT").toString());
```

but the output of above parsed date is still in 24 hours format instead of 12 hours AM/PM.

if I am using `hh` instead of `HH` why my output is incorrect ?
I have also tried `KK` already but didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but the output of above parsed date is still in 24 hours format instead of 12 hours AM/PM.

You've *parsed* the value using `hh`, but the *output* is just what you get from calling [`Date.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--):

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> ```
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
> ```
>
> where:
>   ...
>   hh is the hour of the day (00 through 23), as two decimal digits.

The fact that you *parsed* using a 12-hour time of day is irrelevant to the output of `Date.toString()`. A `Date` doesn't have any clue about format, or time zone, or calendar - it's *just* an instant in time. (Internally, a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.)

If you need to convert a `Date` to a `String` in a particular format, you should use `DateFormat.format` to do so.

I would also *strongly* discourage you from using a parsing format which uses `hh` but without an AM/PM designator - do you really only want to be able to represent values which occur in the morning?

Are you really *sure* that your input data is in 12-hour format? It seems unlikely to me - in particular, when the hour is zero-padded, that *usually* indicates that it's in a 24-hour format. The lack of an AM/PM specifier suggests that again.

Comment: thank you for your answer Sir, I am trying to understand it, just one more query, even if i use `Calendar` to print this time it still prints in 24-hours ? `Calendar s = Calendar.getInstance();`
`s.setTime(sdf.parse("Jan 30 2014 09:07:32 GMT"));` then `System.out.println(s.getTime());`

Comment: @bhuvesh: That's *still* calling `Date.toString()`. Why did you expect it to work any differently?

Answer (score 2):

I get `Thu Jan 30 10:07:32 CET 2014`. This is because `Date::toString()` returns the date in a localized represantation. To get the desired output, you have to use another `DateFormat` like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatForParsing = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss Z");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatForOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("ha");
Date parsedDate = dateFormatForParsing.parse("Jan 30 2014 09:07:32 GMT");

System.out.println(dateFormatForOutput.format(parsedDate));
```

This outputs `10AM`.